# equivalent of a c# class in c /CLI when used as a parameter(managed) for a function in c /CLI

Tags: c#, com, c++-cli, dllexport, firebreath

I have a c# file as below:

```
//MyHandler.cs
public **class MyHandler**
{
**Function1(IntPtr handle)**
{....}
Function2(MyImageHandler myImgHandler,int height,int width)
{....}
};

public **class MyImageHandler**
{
FunctionX(string imagePath,int height,int width)
{.....}
};
```

I am wrapping it using a c++/CLI wrapper dll
which contains a header file as follows :

```
//IWrapper
#pragma once
#include<windows.h>
#include <string>

#ifdef MANAGEDWRAPPER_EXPORTS
#define DLLAPI  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DLLAPI  __declspec(dllimport)
#pragma comment(lib,"D:\\MY\\MYY1\\Wrapper\\Debug\\MyFinalLibrary.lib")
#endif

class IWrapper
{
public:
   virtual DLLAPI void Function1(HWND  handle)=0;
   **virtual __stdcall void Function2(MyImageHandler myImageHandler,int width,int height)=0;**
};
```

** MyImageHandler is a managed class.so i am exporting it through __stdcall.Am i right in doing this? **
Now i have a header file implementing the above header file  and then a cpp file as follows::

```
#include "Wrapper.h"
#include "IWrapper.h"
#include<vcclr.h>
#include <windows.h>
Function1(HWND handle)
{....}
Function2(MyImageHandler myImgHandler,int height,int weight)
{
//Here I need to typecast the MyImageHandler type to a managed handle
}
```

Comment: Basically I wanted myImgHandler to be casted to <MyImageHandler^> so that i can access FunctionX() in the c# class of MyImageHandler.How to do that?

Comment: I think it should already be declared as `MyImageHandler^` from the start in your C++/CLI code, since it's a ref class.

Comment: @Medinoc but it seems that c++/cli can't export functions with managed parameters having __clr calling convention.If it can be how is it exported?My main objective is to access the functionX()

Comment: You want to export this stuff for *what*? Managed applications, or unmanaged applications? If the former, just make a public managed class. If the latter, I don't think it works that way (what with hosting the runtime et. al.); you should make a COM-Visible C# assembly instead.

Comment: making a firebreath plugin which is a native c++. Can't opt that method @Medinoc .Any other suggestions

Comment: @Medinoc Sir,I have already created the c# class library.whose framework has been shown in the question

Comment: Scratch my comment, I've just tested it on Visual Studio 2005 (C# DLL, C++/CLI DLL, native C application, directly calling a free function) and it worked seamlessly.

Comment: If your C code is to hold references to managed objects for future calls to the managed functions, these references should be in `intptr_t` values on the C end; On the C++/CLI end, they shall be the managed `IntPtr` values returned by the `GCHandle` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this on Visual Studio 2005, which worked:

```
//Project: InteropTestCsLib, class1.cs
namespace InteropTestCsLib
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int Add(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
    }
}
```

A C++/CLI project with an assembly reference to the C# one, and the project link option "Ignore import library" disabled (it was enabled by default)

```
//Project: InteropTestCppCliLib, InteropTestCppCliLib.h
namespace InteropTestCppCliLib {

    public ref class MyWrapper abstract sealed
    {
    public:
        static int Add(int a, int b);
    };
}
```

```
//Project: InteropTestCppCliLib, InteropTestCppCliLib.cpp
namespace InteropTestCppCliLib {

int MyWrapper::Add(int a, int b)
{
    InteropTestCsLib::Class1^ obj = gcnew InteropTestCsLib::Class1();
    return obj->Add(a, b);
}

}

//Free function, neither in a namespace nor class, but still managed code
extern "C" int __stdcall MyWrapperAdd(int a, int b)
{
    return InteropTestCppCliLib::MyWrapper::Add(a, b);
}
```

And the module-definition file (.def):

```
LIBRARY "InteropTestCppCliLib"
EXPORTS
    MyWrapperAdd
```

And finally an empty native Win32 C/C++ project, with a project dependency on the C++/CLI DLL (or simply, a project that imports the import library it generated):

```
/*Project: InteropTestUnmanagedApp, main.c*/
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall MyWrapperAdd(int a, int b);

int main(void)
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 32;
    int result = MyWrapperAdd(x, y);
    printf("%d + %d = %d\n", x, y, result);
    return 0;
}
```

The C project called the C++/CLI one seamlessly.